# Installing Watir-Web Driver on Fedora Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, watir, webdriver

I'm trying to install watir-webdriver by using `gem install watir-webdriver` on Linux.  I have installed ruby 1.8.6, activesupport 2.3.8 as well as firewatir.  However, when I try to install watir-webdriver, I get the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing watir-webdriver:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
can't find header files for ruby.
```

(btw, for a bit of context - I'm a complete Linux newbie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you installed ruby with yum, you'll need the rpm for development headers.

```
sudo yum install ruby-devel
```

and try again.